# Clean URLs are a little bit too clean

Tags: drupal, upgrade, redirect

Drupal 7.9, CiviCRM 5.51 ( recently partially updated from v.4.7 ).
Something overrides CiviCRM URLs in the menu:
instead of **&contribute?reset=1** it comes as ***contribute_reset_1***
Drupal  **.htaccess** file has no alterations, nor there are any custom module or custom theme function. Vanilla civicrm.settings.php. There is another civicrm setup on the same server  which works as it should. So there is a big chance something has been rotten during the upgrade but it's unclear where to start looking. Any advice please!

Comment: There's not much overlap in php compatibility between those two versions of civicrm, how did you deal with that?

Comment: @AlanDixon Well, the work is in progress, so to say. A few missing DB tables here and there. DB triggers broken. Bunch of Integrity constraint violation. Menu is not working. Still, I hope to get there before the xmas :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nice post title!

You could try civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1

If that doesn't work, a first step might be check if they are stored in civicrm_navigation with the underscore, or whether something is translating them on the fly.

Also check if there is a custom php dir set at admin - system settings - directories and see if there are any overrides in that folder.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately few menu rebuilds made  no difference and there is no custom_php/custom_tpl folders. civicrm_navigation items look legit: all ampersands and question marks are in place. Interesting enough, not all links are affected. For instance, Financial Types  /civicrm/admin/financial/financialType?reset=1 is fine but the next one, Financial Accounts, has been "cleared" like this: /civicrm/admin/financial/financialAccount_reset_1

Comment: Hmm. That is really odd. Any difference between whether the link is absolute vs relative? i.e. is it only replacing relative ones? Any weird in code in drupal settings.php?

Comment: all links in ciivicrm_navigation table are relatiave and settings.php is vanilla ( except of db connection string )