# Drupal Clean URL disable breaks CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, angular, resource-urls

In addition to [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42296/clean-urls-are-a-little-bit-too-clean) question:
disabling Clean URLs in Drupal [7.90] somehow breaks CiviCRM resources load with cryptic errors in Dev Console:

```
Error: CRM.url called before initialization Common.js?rf6a3f:1674 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'back') crm.ajax.js?rf6a3f:34
```

It also looks like some CSS and JS resource fail to load, because of :

```
  Refused to execute script from 'https://domain/index.php?rf6a3f' 
  Refused to apply style from 'https://domain/index.php?rf6a3f'
```

Resource URLs and  Directores paths   are triple-checked and all real paths on the server exist and writable. Backend / Menu rebuild make no difference. Cache is crystal clean.
Basically, all filesystem is new and shiny, no custom Drupal code nor CiviCRM custom extension. The only place where the problem might be is the database.  "**civicrm_domain.config_backend**" is null.

So the question is: which table(s) in the database holds information about  path(s) and/or resources loaded ?

Drupal 7.9, CiviCRM 5.51.1

Comment: have you checked civicrm.settings.php?

Comment: More than once: the only lines changed are databases connection and paths: nothing unusual. Drupal pathauto is disabled. All files are fresh and all possible customizations are eliminated. All Drupal Watchdog messages and CiviCRM logs and Apache/PHP error logs are checked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're probably seeing symptoms of a deeper problem, e.g. php version.

> re: "So the question is: which table(s) in the database holds information about path(s) and/or resources loaded ?"

The answer is probably not what you're hoping for. CiviCRM has some of that, which gets built/cached, but makes use of civicrm settings + Drupal. Drupal is the initial 'dispatcher' and the lack of any path suggests that civicrm is not telling Drupal what paths it controls properly.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Any hint re: how to politely ask civicrm to talk to drupal in a nice manner? I'm thinking of having a better look inside of  CRM_Core_Config::singleton() and/or CRM_Utils_System::languageNegotiationURL().

Comment: Since php version was mentioned ... what version of php is being used?

Comment: @yurg - although I applaud your willingness to dive into the code, I suspect that's not your best approach. But to answer your question, I'd start in the drupal module portion of the CiviCRM code (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/civicrm.module) and go from the hook_menu function. And look for errors in your log files ...

Comment: @Aidan It is 7.4 currently

Comment: @AlanDixon Thank you for the pointer: I'd very much loved not to dive into the code, however with CiviCRM 4.3 to 5.51 migration there are not  much options left.